# Hide get parametres

Tags: php, .htaccess

Get:

```
https://xxx.ru/page/?page=update-1/
```

how to show:

```
https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/
```

I tried does not work
.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page\/(.*?)/?$ page/?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page/\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ page/?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page/?page=$1 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL:

`https://xxx.ru/page/update-1/`